# Как поменять цвет контролов тега audio?

Tags: css, html5

Имеется html5 тэг audio. Я в списке webkit нашел как поменять цвет таймлапса, но не нашел как поменять цвет контрола. Подскажите, для какого свойства нужно указать цвет?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD: Для примера взял все параметры из списка, на который указал @Arsen
Цвет интересующих меня контролов не поменялся

```css
audio::-webkit-media-controls-panel,
   audio::-webkit-media-controls-mute-button,
   audio::-webkit-media-controls-play-button,
   audio::-webkit-media-controls-timeline-container,
   audio::-webkit-media-controls-current-time-display,
   audio::-webkit-media-controls-time-remaining-display,
   audio::-webkit-media-controls-timeline,
   audio::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider-container,
   audio::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider,
   audio::-webkit-media-controls-seek-back-button,
   audio::-webkit-media-controls-seek-forward-button,
   audio::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-button,
   audio::-webkit-media-controls-rewind-button,
   audio::-webkit-media-controls-return-to-realtime-button,
   audio::-webkit-media-controls-toggle-closed-captions-button {
    background: yellow;
    color: yellow;
 
   }
```

```html
<audio src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.ogg" controls>
```

Результат из примера:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: насколько помню, тут должно быть, https://gist.github.com/afabbro/3759334

Comment: @Arsen Да, я там смотрел, но не нашел нужного элемента в <audio>.

Comment: хмм, странно, я помню что там должен быть, просто не помню точное имя ))

Comment: У меня цвет поменялся, только заметье что это только для Хрома. так как идёт префикс `-webkit`

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин У меня в хроме поменялся цвет для всего, кроме контролов, отмеченных стрелочкой в вопросе

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин Они желтые должны быть.

Comment: @Igor у всех разные... и да, задано жёлтые а у меня ораньжевые ))

Comment: В IE вообще по-другому все выглядит. Похоже, придется делать обертку и js применять

Comment: Ясно, у меня Yandex browser видимо тут другой стиль стоит.

Comment: Можно узнать какой цвет вы хотите для этого сделать?

Comment: @StackOverflow Любой другой. Например, красный

Answer (score 5, accepted):

То что стрелкой автор отметил можно убрать вот примерно так. Используя `css` [фильтры](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/filter).

Но поскольку тут везде написан префикс `webkit` то все это будет работать в хроме и на некоторых браузерах то же, но не на `mozilla firefox`.

```css
audio::-webkit-media-controls-panel,
audio::-webkit-media-controls-mute-button,
audio::-webkit-media-controls-play-button,
audio::-webkit-media-controls-time-remaining-display,
audio::-webkit-media-controls-current-time-display {
  color: yellow;
  background: yellow
}
audio::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider {
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(195deg) saturate(100);
}
audio::-webkit-media-controls-timeline {
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(195deg) saturate(100);
}
```

```html
<audio src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.ogg" controls>
```

Comment: @ilyaplot если хотите другой цвет то манипулируйте фильтрами и получите цвета.